# Why do I have three My Documents folders?

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables, user-profiles, my-documents

I'm trying to fix my profile on Windows 7. Currently

- %USERPROFILE% points to `C:\Users\myUsername`
- My Documents is also at `C:\Users\myUsername`
- `\\profileServer\profiles$\myUsername` has TWO "My Documents" folders
- Neither of these folders contain what's in `C:\Users\myUsername\My Documents`
- Navigating to `%USERPROFILE%` in Windows Explorer displays two copies of everything, one local and one copy from the server.
- Programs use sort of a toss up between `C:\Users\myUsername\My Documents` or one of the two My Documents on profileServer.

According to our sysadmins, My Documents is supposed to point to the profile server, but other folders should be local.

How can I fix this so I have ONE copy of everything, with My Documents pointing to `\\profileServer\profiles$\myUsername\Documents` and everything else local?

To be honest, I don't understand why this is so difficult and confusing. For example, why does Windows allow displaying two folders with the same name in the same directory?

And why does inputting `C:\Users\myUsername` and `%USERPROFILE%` into Windows Explorer produce two different results? They should be identical.

Some screenshots

My directory on the profileServer

[image]

My local user directory, `C:\Users\myUsername`

[image]

Navigating to `%USERPROFILE%` in Windows Explorer

[image]

Showing that `%USERPROFILE%` is set to a local directory

[image]

Comment: Are you the system administrator? Got access to Active Directory?

Comment: It looks like your user profile is corrupt.

Comment: @Amicable I am not the system administrator, nor do I have access to AD. I am a local admin on my machine.

Comment: @Ramhound How can you tell?

Answer (score 4):

I hope I have your answer! I believe I reproduced this by copying the desktop.ini (hidden) file from the real my documents folder to any other named folder. This forces the look and feel of that folder to be My Documents even though it's something else.

### To Fix Your Problem

1. In explorer, navigate to the Tools->Folder Options menu
2. Click on the View tab
3. Find the *Hidden files and folders* item and under it, select *Show hidden files, folders, and drives*.
4. Click OK
5. In your %userprofile% folder, you need to identify the fake My Documents. Do this by opening the Property page of both items. One will have a tab named Location. This is your **REAL** My Documents folder.
   [image: The real My Documents and the fake My Documents]
6. On the property page of the fake My Documents folder, click on the Security tab. This will show the location of the folder for your reference.
7. Close the property pages and open up the fake folder
8. Since you enabled Show hidden files in step #3, you will now see a transparent looking **desktop** file. Delete this file and return the previous folder. The original name of the folder will return. (Ignore the icon in my picture, I have this file associated with notepad++)
   [image: desktop ini file controlling the look and feel of the folder]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the location of your Documents folder, add more etc by Right Clicking on your "Documents" folder.

(Note, "Documents" folder under Libraries. Not "My Documents")

[image]

Either the folder itself, or the Start Menu shortcut is fine.

This window will pop up.
You might have multiple folders listed here?

[image: Window like so]

You can then change the location of the libraries here.

Comment: I do not see a window like this. http://i.stack.imgur.com/jthKw.png

Comment: @root45 You've brought up the folder options for "My Documents" which is just a normal folder. Edited answer.

Comment: Okay, I found what you are talking about. [I only have one folder listed there.](http://i.imgur.com/S7I5I.png) This doesn't seem to explain the two copies on the server plus my local copy. Moreover, when I save things to my local copy it doesn't appear on the server.